# List two columns - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, order-by

i have a table like this:

```
cp1   | cp2
-----------
A     | 5  
A     | 1  
A     | 1  
B     | 3  
C     | 4
```

and i want to create a query like this:

```
cp1 |  cp2 
----------- 
A   |  5   
A   |  1   
A   |  1   
C   |  4   
B   |  3
```

my query is to sort by the largest numbers at the top and gathering the same letters in the column cp1, simplifying the letters should group together and the top number above.

Comment: can you elaborate more of your instructions. cause i cant get how did c4 placed over b3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with zxc that your instructions are not clear. However I think what you are asking for is to get the highest number and group together all the letters that have an instance of that number. Then go to the next highest number. Is correct? I did this in SQL Server but it ought to work in MySQL as well.

```
--populate my temp table. I threw in some D's just to double check my logic 
DECLARE @Tmp table (cp1 varchar(8), cp2 int) 
INSERT INTO @Tmp (cp1, cp2)
    SELECT 'A' 'cp1', 5 'cp2' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A' 'cp1', 1 'cp2' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A' 'cp1', 1 'cp2' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'D' 'cp1', 5 'cp2' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'D' 'cp1', 1 'cp2' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'B' 'cp1', 3 'cp2' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'C' 'cp1', 4 'cp2' 

--this returns the ordering column for visibility during testing
SELECT *, (SELECT max(cp2) FROM @Tmp WHERE cp1 = t.cp1) 'Ordering'  
FROM @Tmp t 
ORDER BY Ordering DESC, cp1 

--but this should work too 
SELECT *
FROM @Tmp t 
ORDER BY (SELECT max(cp2) FROM @Tmp WHERE cp1 = t.cp1) DESC, cp1
```

Comment: It Worked with the two queries, thanks alot!!!